# Radio streaming in smartface app studio

Tags: android, mobile, smartface.io

I am using video object for radio streaming. The problem is that when i clicked the play button, main screen disappears and logo of the QuickTime appears on the black screen. I want that start radio stream in the background.

Does Smartface present us play pls or m3u file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no certain way to play *.pls or *.m3u files. Because it requires media player to play them. (not an exact videoPlayer)

Try to do this in WebView. I just suggest you this idea.